# free only-online file (pdf) viewer

Tags: jquery, flash, apache-flex, pdf, readonly

What is the best free resource to use for the purpose of letting users view files (pdf)  online without any option for them to download those files in any way?

Flexpaper could be a solution but it is said [here](http://vigrond.com/blog/2011/06/05/protecting-pdfs-using-flexpaper/) that:

> Natively, FlexPaper does not protect PDFs from being printed or
>   copied.  It actually lacks options for doing so on the JavaScript
>   front-end.  However in its Commercial License (to take the branding
>   off for 1 domain) contains a ReadOnly parameter to disable printing &
>   copying.

N.B: I want to use php for scripting purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of the blog that you linked to.  In the article I provide a compiled version of FlexPaper with the readonly option set to true.

This will provide a deterrent to people trying to download or print them.

Like others have said here, there is no true protection as long as you have control over the environment (your computer) that your viewing the PDF in.

Here is the link again: [Protecting PDFs using FlexPaper](http://vigrond.com/blog/2011/06/05/protecting-pdfs-using-flexpaper)

Comment: can't Url Snooper (http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/urlsnooper/index.html) or Firebug find out the address of the file being displayed in swf format so that the file can be downloaded with Flashget or Download accelerator?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing that can be viewed online can be prevented from being stolen or printed. If your material must not be used in ways you do not wish, you must first accept that this is an impossible goal, and second use some form of legal protection such as a signed non-disclosure agreement prior to delivery of this material.

Comment: so you want to say that all the google books can be downloaded in some way?

Comment: If Google gives you the ability to see it, then yes, it can be kept by the viewer, printed, anything one can do with a normal file.

Comment: oh i see. i could not understand your 'non-disclosure agreement' point.

Comment: any response to my last comment to Vigrond ?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of response you would expect, but I stand by my original statement that you cannot make something available online and prevent it from bring used against your wishes (using only technical means, or even using legal means if they are not easy enough to enforce).

Comment: 'if they are not easy enough '- should be 'those' instead of 'they',- I think.

Comment: This answer provides no help or insight. You can't stop anyone from doing anything (obviously), but you can take steps to make it more difficult or impractical, which might be more than enough if your target audience is a user who isn't technical.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan the question asks very directly how to have readers access the data _without any option for them to download those files in any way_. As you agree this is an impossible task; the question asker clearly believed that the task would be possible therefore I feel my answer does provide insight. Sometimes the right answer is simply: that can't be done. As to "making it more difficult or impractical"... taking a screenshot is never difficult nor impractical, therefore the best one can hope for in this task is to create extra work for themselves and to not slow down their reader at all.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best option is to use a PDF renderer on the server and supply the pages as PNGs or JPEGs. Naturally anyona can recompile a PDF based upon some PDFs but they will lose resolution, links, scalable graphic/fonts etc.

Anything that renders on the client (bitmaps, HTML, PDFs) can be easily ripped, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: any  reference to such a renderer ? I'll use php

Comment: I do not know exactly what renderer will be easy to use for PHP but if you Google for "pdf to png" you get quite a lot of hits for Windows and/or Linux based software. I never looked for PHP bindings..

Comment: any response to my last comment to Vigrond ?